# Extracing Outer Points On Edge of a Shape

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I need a good method for demonstrating outside of a shape using points. I need an algorithm to give me some points located on the outside of a shape.

What's a good start?

[image]

Comment: You want to vectorice your Image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV has solution for you, but it depends on accuracy. You can start from [approximate chain](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxchains) -- it will approximate your shape by polygonal curve and gives you vertex coordinates. You can always make it more precise testing it by[pointpolygontest OpenCV function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#pointpolygontest) or fitting by [fitLine function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#fitline). Sure you need first to find edges (openCV has Canny edge detection etc) and countours first (see  links above for findContours function description). So your steps are:

1. find Edges
2. find contour
3. approximate contour by polygonal curve
4. fit polygonal curve

Answer (score 1):

This is called Hull finding. In the normal case you would want to find the Convex Hull but your example shows a Concave Hull. If your shape is generated via a Spline, then the Spline algorithm you are using should be generating a set of edge points from the Control Points you are inputting. However if your shape is entirely random (i.e. not generated from a mathematical model) then you will need to use a different technique more akin to an Edge Detection graphics pass (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) like this one. (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93642/Canny-Edge-Detection-in-C)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

- Dilate your shape by `3x3` square element
- Subtract original image from current
- This will give you the borders
- Use any line tracing algorithm to find the boundary.

Comment: Why dilate and subtract for boundary if we have edge detection? I'm curious.

Comment: @PervezAlam In most implementations its faster